# Full width container inside a fixed width, without page x-scrolbar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a full-width class, which can be used inside a fixed-width container.

I found different solutions. Some of them are using fixed or absolute positioning, which is not convenient to me.

Imagine this:

```
<div style="max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto">
    Some fixed-width content

    <div class="full-width" style="background-color: red; text-align: right">
        Some full-width content
    </div>
</div>
```

I found a solution like that:

```
.full-width {
    margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
    margin-right: calc(50% - 50vw);
    max-width: 100vw;
    width: 100vw;
    display: block;
}
```

It works somewhat well, but when the page content is enough for a vertical scrollbar to appear, the container width becomes slightly wider than the page and a horizontal scrollbar appears.

Putting overflow-x: hidden on the body element is not an option, because some content from the container will be clipped (a whole letter will disappear if the text is right-aligned).

I tried with different widths and widths keywords, but with no result. The vertical scrollbar width is unknown. I am not using any frameworks or libraries.

I want this to be a universal solution because it will be used in a lot of cases, where rearranging the Html markup will not be possible. I don't want that unnecessary horizontal scrollbar, but still, the container should reach the edge of the page without any content cutting.

Comment: Several different approaches here, https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/

Comment: Thank you CBroe, but I am looking for an approach that works with a vertical scrollbar too.

Comment: Not sure there is a proper solution, without taking the scrollbar width into account explicitly. You need the `100vw` here, because `100%` will only be the width of the limited width parent element, but 100vw does not change based on whether there is currently a scrollbar visible or not.